# How do I give PHP write access to a directory?

Tags: php, file-permissions, chmod

I'm trying to use PHP to create a file, but it isn't working. I am assuming this is because it doesn't have write access (it's always been the problem before). I tried to test if this was the problem by making the folder chmod 0777, but that just ended up making every script in that directory return a 500 error message until I changed it back.
How do I give PHP write access to my file system so it can a create a file?

Edit: It is hosted on Hostgator shared hosting using Apache.

Edit 2: Someone asked for the code:
The code is a GD image script. I know the rest of it works as previously I was creating the image every ime it was called. Now I am trying to create them when new text is added and save them to a folder. The write line I have is:
imagejpeg(null,$file,85);

I also created a test file to check if it was just a broken script (mainly copied from tizag):
http://gearboxshow.info/rkr/lesig.jpg/testfile.txt (I don't know if/how to post the code here properly. Here is the contents of the PHP script, minus PHP tags.)

It returns 13,13,1 (separate lines), so it looks as if it thinks it wrote something, but the testfile.txt is blank (I uploaded a blank one), or non-existent (if I delete it).

Edit 3: The server runs CentOS.

Comment: Is this a server you control or are you on a shared server?

Comment: Hostgator shared hosting. Apache.

Comment: What OS is the server running on?  If it's Linux, you should make sure that the apache user (the exact user name will depend on your setup - often httpd or www-data under Linux) has write access to the directory.  You can change the owner to the same user as apache (using chown) and set give the owner write access (e.g. "chmod 755") or you can make it world writable (e.g. "chmod 777").

Comment: @El Yobo: Don't make it 777 ... let's be sensible about chmod please.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

An easy way is to let PHP create the directory itself in the first place.

```
<?php
 $dir = 'myDir';

 // create new directory with 744 permissions if it does not exist yet
 // owner will be the user/group the PHP script is run under
 if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
     mkdir ($dir, 0744);
 }

 file_put_contents ($dir.'/test.txt', 'Hello File');
```

This saves you the hassle with permissions.

Comment: Thats right. You can modify the permissions to meet your needs.

Comment: This is the easiest solution although you should not use 777 on apache as it is configured to block theose files.

Comment: I am getting permission denied when making the directory!

Comment: this assumes you have write access to the folder you want to create myDir in

Comment: your solution says permission denied. thats obvius

Answer (score 46):

## Simple 3-Step Solution

> Abstract: *You need to set the owner of the directory to the user that PHP uses (web server user)*.

---

**Step 1: Determine PHP User**

Create a PHP file containing the following:

```
<?php echo `whoami`; ?>
```

Upload it to your web server. The output should be similar to the following:

```
www-data
```

Therefore, the PHP user is `www-data`.

---

**Step 2: Determine Owner of Directory**

Next, check the details of the web directory via the command line:

```
ls -dl /var/www/example.com/public_html/example-folder
```

The result should be similar to the following:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 exampleuser1 exampleuser2 4096 Mar 29 16:34 example-folder
```

Therefore, the owner of the directory is `exampleuser1`.

---

**Step 3: Change Directory Owner to PHP User**

Afterwards, change the owner of the web directory to the PHP user:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/example.com/public_html/example-folder
```

Verify that the owner of the web directory has been changed:

```
ls -dl /var/www/example.com/public_html/example-folder
```

The result should be similar to the following:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data exampleuser2 4096 Mar 29 16:34 example-folder
```

Therefore, the owner of `example-folder` has successfully been changed to the PHP user: `www-data`.

---

**Done! PHP should now be able to write to the directory.**

Comment: Totally OT here, but there was no other way to ping you: Thanks for your dilligent tagging effort over at Coffee SE!

Comment: @Stephie No problem!

Comment: Very good step-by-step manual, thanks you a lot! I would add little bit. I solved problem with writing file to vagrant shared folder inside of vagrant machine, which runs apache using your manual, but, firstly, I had to set chmod -R 0777 to shared folder on my local PC (which contains vagrant machine).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. No changes needed to get my PHP script to find the directory writable.

Comment: This worked very well! This should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: please this is not working. `is_writable($directory)` still gives me false

Answer (score 39):

Set the owner of the directory to the user running apache. Often nobody on linux

```
chown nobody:nobody <dirname>
```

This way your folder will not be world writable, but still writable for apache :)

Comment: If you use Ubuntu, this user and group does not exist.  Any suggestions to accomplish what you're doing here then?

Comment: @BrandonMinton 'chown www-data:www-data <dirname>' should do it. www-data is the apache user on debian based systems

Comment: hello, you said need to `chown nobody:nobody <dirname>` where do i have to code this?

Comment: @guitarlass you will need to put that command into a bash/ssh window

Comment: Sometimes is `apache:apache`. See this awesome answer to find out — http://stackoverflow.com/a/8924481/535406

Comment: sometimes I don't get why things work or don't work when it comes to permissions, and I'm glad this just worked.....hot diggity dog.

Comment: @ThomasWinsnes `www-data:www-data` is still not writable for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thomas Winsnes you are a godsend :), thanks for your comment, that should be the real answer.  The www-data:www-data group that is

Comment: lm Fedora , user and group for httpd is apache. it didnt work

Answer (score 11):

1st Figure out which user is owning httpd process using the following command

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

you will get a several line response like this:

```
phpuser   17121  0.0  0.2 414060  7928 ?        SN   03:49   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Here 1st column shows the user name. So now you know the user who is trying to write files, which is in this case `phpuser`
You can now go ahead and set the permission for directory where your php script is trying to write something:

```
sudo chown phpuser:phpuser PhpCanWriteHere
sudo chmod 755 PhpCanWriteHere
```

Comment: You have to use `ps aux | grep apache2` nowadays.

Comment: that not worked for me sry pal

Answer (score 4):

You can change the permissions of a folder with PHP's chmod(). More information on how to use the command is here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

If you get a 500 Error when setting the permissions to 777 (world writable), then it means your server is setup to prevent executing such files. This is done for security reasons. In that case, you will want to use 755 as the highest permissions on a file.

If there is an error_log file that is generated in the folder where you are executing the PHP document, you will want to view the last few entries. This will give you an idea where the script is failing.

For help with PHP file manipulation, I use http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php as a resource.

Comment: The folder is already currently set at 0755 as default.
I never thought of checking the error_log, but I just did and it doesn't contain anything about why it was failing to produce the files.

Comment: It might be a good idea to post the code you are having trouble with. A nice resource I use on occasion for file handler syntax help is http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php.

Answer (score 4):

I found out that with HostGator you have to set files to CMOD 644 and Folders to 755. Since I did this based on their tech support it works with HostGator

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem:

As I was reluctant to give 0777 to my php directory, **I create a tmp directory with rights 0777, where I create the files I need to write to.**

My php directory continue to be protected. If somebody hackes the tmp directory, the site continue to work as usual.

Answer (score 4):

You can set selinux to permissive in order to analyze.

```
    # setenforce 0
```

Selinux will log but permit acesses. So you can check the `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for details. Maybe you will need change selinux context. Fot this, you will use `chcon` command. If you need, show us your `audit.log` to more detailed answer.

Don't forget to enable selinux after you solved the problem. It better keep selinux enforced.

```
    # setenforce 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Best way in giving write access to a directory..

```
$dst = "path/to/directory";
mkdir($dst); 
chown($dst, "ownername");
chgrp($dst, "groupname");
exec ("find ".$dst." -type d -exec chmod 0777 {} +");
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm running Ubuntu, and as said above nobody:nobody does not work on Ubuntu. You get the error:

```
chown: invalid group: 'nobody:nobody'
```

Instead you should use the 'nogroup', like:

```
chown nobody:nogroup <dirname>
```

Answer (score 2):

chmod does not allow you to set ownership of a file.  To set the ownership of the file you must use the chown command.

Comment: i changed the owner and still acess denied

Answer (score -1):

Tiny little hint!

echo `whoami`;

make sure you use BACK QUOTES  
NOT
single quotes ' '
!

(of course now the back quotes don't show up in this editor! oh well, I tried!)