# How to specify a export-path, with sql in php?

Tags: php, mysql

**Background:** I work with phpMyAdmin (MySQL Workbench) in a mysql DB. I write some PHP code to *import* data in the DB and execute this with the task scheduler of windows. <= this works fine!

**My Topic:** Now I want to *export* some data into a file in a Windows folder. At first I write the SQL code in phpMyAdmin to see some debug-infos.
Independent of php my sql-query works fine.

If I put the code in the php-programm my export didn't work.
I think the problem occurs because of my path specification.
The other programmparts, specially the Update-Part, do what they should.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

include "../config.php";
$conn = new mysqli('192.168.10.120', 'alb5', 'alb5','testdatenbank');
if ( $conn->connect_error ) {
    die( "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error );
} //$conn->connect_error


$sql = "set @sql = concat(\"SELECT `LS_ID_Nr`, `Stk_pro_Krt_DL` * `Krt_DL` + `RB_Stk_pro_Krt_DL` * `RB_Krt_DL`, `Umstellzeit`, `Produktionszeit`, `Teilmeldung`, `Fertigmeldung` 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Temp/Export/Test - \", DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s'),\" - Test.txt' 
fields terminated by ';' 
lines terminated by '\r\n' 
From praemie where Proof_P = 0\");";

$sql = "prepare s1 from @sql;";
$sql = "execute s1;";
$sql = "DROP PREPARE s1;";
$sql = "UPDATE praemie SET Proof_P = 1 WHERE Proof_P = 0;";

    $result           = $conn->query( $sql );
echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
?>
```

Does anybody have an idea how I specify a export-path, with sql in php?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is creepy way of doing this.

I suggest to fetch the data into the php and store it via `file_put_contents`.

Quick example:

```
<?php
include "../config.php";
$conn = new mysqli('192.168.10.120', 'alb5', 'alb5','testdatenbank');
if ( $conn->connect_error ) {
    die( "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error );
} //$conn->connect_error

$query = 'SELECT `LS_ID_Nr` AS `LS_ID_Nr`, `Stk_pro_Krt_DL` * `Krt_DL` + `RB_Stk_pro_Krt_DL` * `RB_Krt_DL` AS ``, `Umstellzeit`, `Produktionszeit`, `Teilmeldung`, `Fertigmeldung`FROM praemie WHERE Proof_P = 0';

$result = $conn->query($sql);

file_put_contents('C:/Temp/Export/Test/test.txt', json_encode($result->fetch_all()));
```

Comment: Hey Damian, thanks for your answer. Can you briefly explain what your example is doing.

Comment: Hey Damian,
at first: cool feature is the "Select As" part. So I can give the long stuff "`Stk_pro_Krt_DL` * `Krt_DL`....." a short mark. Thanks for that.
Can you briefly explain what your example is doing. 
I try to make it suitable for my code. The query, in mySQL Workbench, get the correct result, but the export still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @N.Wieczorek. This will query the data from the database and put the results it into `$result` variable. Then the all data from results is pulled via `$result->fetch_all()` and it is passed into the `json_encode` function which encodes the data into json format. The result of this function is put into `file_put_contents` which puts a json string into a specific file :)

Comment: @N.Wieczorek please take a look at this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574927/exporting-mysql-table-to-txt-or-doc-file-using-php

Comment: I'll take a look at it right away. Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

yeeeah it works now!
Only for other people out there who want do the same.

Two things I have to change. I execute my programm in an other path so I have to write
`$include_path = 'C:/xampp/php/pear/PEAR/config.php';` this fixed the first error.

The second point: Your quick example `$result = $conn->query($sql);` have to be `$result = $conn->query($query);`

Down below is the whole code:

```
<?php

$include_path = 'C:/xampp/php/pear/PEAR/config.php';
$conn = new mysqli('192.168.10.120', 'alb5', 'alb5','testdatenbank');
if ( $conn->connect_error ) {
    die( "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error );
} //$conn->connect_error


$query = 'SELECT `LS_ID_Nr`, `Stk_pro_Krt_DL` * `Krt_DL` + `RB_Stk_pro_Krt_DL` * `RB_Krt_DL` AS `Ges. Stück`, `Umstellzeit`, `Produktionszeit`, `Teilmeldung`, `Fertigmeldung` FROM praemie WHERE Proof_P = 0';

$result = $conn->query($query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)!==0)
{
    file_put_contents('C:/Temp/Export/' . date('Y-m-d H-i-s') . '.txt', json_encode($result->fetch_all()));
} 

$sql = "UPDATE praemie SET Proof_P = 1 WHERE Proof_P = 0";

$result = $conn->query( $sql );
echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
?>
```

*Edit: I integrate a proof if the result (num_rows of query) is not equal to zero and give the file a unique name with the variable `date('Y-m-d H-i-s')` (attention with windows filename permissions H **-** i **-** s not H **:** i **:** s)

**Thanks alot Damian** for all your knowledge and the help of the forum!

I'm happy now.

(~: First attempts with php and it works now fine! :~)