# mkdir always sets folders to read-only?

Tags: php, mkdir

i am trying to create folders from within php. Whenever i use the mkdir function with permission 0777 i get a read-only folder. I want this folder to be read & write. 
The parent folder (`drive/`) is fully writable and readable for every user.

This is what i use: `mkdir(ABSPATH . 'drive/' . $folderName, 0777);`

I have also tried to use it without any additional paramaters: `mkdir(ABSPATH . 'drive/' . $folderName);`

Any ideas why this is and how to fix this so that i can generate folders that has write access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a shared environment, mkdir fails to set the permissions properly. A workaround is to set the chmod with [chmod()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) after you've created the directory.

Comment: It works, thanks. Weird that in a share environment it fails to set it within the function but after file creation and chmodding it, it magically has read & write permission..

Answer (score 1):

You can have write permission too with `mkdir`..Here is the code

```
<?php
 $dir = 'myDir';
 // create new directory with 744 permissions if it does not exist yet
 // owner will be the user/group the PHP script is run under

 if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
mkdir ($dir, 0744);
}

 file_put_contents ($dir.'/test.txt', 'Hello File');
```

Found the source from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900690/how-do-i-give-php-write-access-to-a-directory)

Comment: This is in accordance with the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php. Note that the mode is ignored on Windows.

Comment: On Windows there are no real permissions like on UNIX. That's one of the reason I don't have any problems with my script doing file uploads and then re-arranging things and talk to ffmpeg, while on UNIX I do have problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

the issue probably is the mask :)

```
if (!function_exists('mkdir_r')) {
    /**
     * create directory recursively
     * @param $dirName
     * @param int $rights
     * @param string $dir_separator
     * @return bool
     */
    function mkdir_r($dirName, $rights = 0744, $dir_separator = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) {
        $dirs = explode($dir_separator, $dirName);
        $dir = '';
        $created = false;
        foreach ($dirs as $part) {
            $dir .= $part . $dir_separator;
            if (!is_dir($dir) && strlen($dir) > 0) {
                $created = mkdir($dir, $rights);
            }
        }
        return $created;
    }
}

if (!function_exists('ensure_dir')) {
    /**
     * ensure directory exist if not create 
     * @param $dir_path
     * @param int $mode
     * @param bool $use_mask
     * @param int $mask
     * @return bool
     */
    function ensure_dir($dir_path, $mode = 0744, $use_mask = true, $mask = 0002) {
        // set new mask 
        $old_mask = $use_mask && $mask != null
            ? umask($mask)
            : null;
        try {
            return is_dir($dir_path) || mkdir_r($dir_path, $mode);
        } finally {
            if ($use_mask && $old_mask != null) {
                // restore original mask 
                umask($old_mask);
            }
        }
    }
}
```