# mkdir() permission unaltered

Tags: php, apache, permissions, mkdir

I am creating a image upload functionality using php.
I was working on Windows using vagrant and everything worked fine. Now, I moved to Ubuntu (still using vagrant) and the script does not work anymore.
I create two folders, before I upload the image and just the first one is created at the moment.

```
$folder_name = Config::get('PATH_IMAGES') . Session::get('user_id') . '/';
$profile_folder = $folder_name . 'profile/';

// create a folder for the user's images
if (!(is_dir($folder_name) || is_writable($folder_name))) {
    mkdir($folder_name, 0777);
}           

if (!(is_dir($profile_folder) || is_writable($profile_folder))) {
    mkdir($profile_folder, 0777, true);
}
```

This creates one folder with the following permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Aug 9 21.33 folder_name
```

Not drwxrwxrwx! 
Now, if I change the permissions manually (`chmod -R 777 folder_name`), I get the following:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 user user 4096 Aug 9 21.33 folder_name
```

Running my script again, will create the second directory. Repeating this process with the second directory I am able to finally upload the image.
What I tried so far:

```
$folder_name = Config::get('PATH_IMAGES') . Session::get('user_id') . '/';
$profile_folder = $folder_name . 'profile/';

// create a folder for the user's images
if (!(is_dir($folder_name) || is_writable($folder_name))) {
    umask(0); <------
    mkdir($folder_name, 0777);
}           

if (!(is_dir($profile_folder) || is_writable($profile_folder))) {
    umask(0); <------
    mkdir($profile_folder, 0777, true);
}
```

This did not solve the problem. Running (`umask();`) returns 18.
Running chmod() after mkdir() did not help either.
My php user is www-data.
My apache user is 'user'.

There are no error messages.

I do not know where else to look for solutions. I would be very thankful for any help.

EDIT:
Putting it all in one statement does not solve the problem either.

```
    $folder_name = Config::get('PATH_IMAGES') . Session::get('user_id') . '/profile/';

    // create a folder for the user's images            
   if (!(is_dir($folder_name) || is_writable($folder_name))) {
        mkdir($folder_name, 0777, true);            
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104990/mkdir-always-sets-folders-to-read-only/25105031#25105031

Comment: @Chalotte Dunosis I tried using chmod() after mkdir() as well, but that did not change anything...

Comment: which are the permissions for the folder that contains folder_name?

Comment: @Juancho Ramone Fully unrestricted (drwxrwxrwx 3 user user 4096 Aug 9 21.52 images)

Comment: Which PHP-Version are you using?

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11

Comment: Can't you create both folders in the same instruction by setting the recursive parameter to TRUE instead?

Comment: the second part is necessary, because I reuse this function in my project. A couple of times, therefore now it is 'profile' (for profile images) somewhere else it will be 'post' (for images uploaded in posts) etc.

Comment: When you used `chmod()` did it return true? Check for that and if it does, check the folders permissions in FTP or SSH.

Comment: It looks like mkdir() sometimes does not like the trailing slashes https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42739
I'd try without them

Comment: @Juancho Ramone that sounds very promising, but how could I create a path without the slashes? (Sorry, I am really new to all this)

Comment: you only need to remove the last slash, change 
`$folder_name = Config::get('PATH_IMAGES') . Session::get('user_id') . '/';
$profile_folder = $folder_name . 'profile/';` to 
`$folder_name = Config::get('PATH_IMAGES') . Session::get('user_id');
$profile_folder = $folder_name . '/' . 'profile';`

Comment: @JuanchoRamone That did not work, unfortunately. Same result. First folder, without unrestricted permissions.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois using ssh to check the permissions gives me the same result. I am not quite sure how to check if chmod returns true, but I do not get any error message running chmod.

Comment: @JuanchoRamone Safe mode was removed with PHP 5.4

Comment: @kringeltorte Add after the first if clausel `die(var_dump(chmod($folder_name, 0777))); `, it will stop script execution and output the return of the chmod().

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thank you for the details! It returns bool(true). Folder permission is still restricted.

Comment: Can you try changing the PHP's user to the same user as Apache and then try again?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I will try that! Might take a moment...

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Apache completely stopped working after changing the php user (Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}). Therefore, I guess I will have to reprovisioion and reinstall vagrant. I will get back to you as soon as I managed to achieve this. Thank you so much for all your help up until here!!

Answer (score 0):

use `chmod($folder,0755)` (or 0777) after `mkdir()`

Comment: Thank you! I tried that back then. I actually never found a solution for it, I think it was something very weird, which was not directly related to the code.