# Dumping a mysql database to gzip doesn't save file on server?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to dump a mysql database (back-up). I have the following script. The passthru works and it downloads the file to the client, but I also want it to save a copy of the back-up .gz file on the server, in the /backup/ folder.
I can't get it to work. The .gz file downloads to the user, but doesn't get put into the /backup folder.

```
    $filename = $thismoment . "_" . $_GET["t"] . ".gz";
    $mime = "application/x-gzip";

    system('mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip > /backup/' . $filename);

    header( "Content-Type: " . $mime );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"' );

    $cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip --best";   

    passthru( $cmd );

    exit(0);
```

Comment: Do you have write permission for that directory? Actually does user `www` have permission ;)

Comment: On a Windows server, how would I make sure that my PHP script can write a file?

Comment: I've re-made the /backup/ directory following this tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900690/how-do-i-give-php-write-access-to-a-directory

And the .txt file gets created. The back-up file however still doesn't.

Comment: Two thoughts. (1) have you confirmed that you have `system()` access on your IIS?  (2) have you tried using the *full windows path* `C:\\backup\\` instead of just `/backup/` ?

Comment: 1. I've also tried exec() if that makes any difference. 2. Still doesn't work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by combining the two commands into one and specifying the full path to the mysqldump (without .exe...)

```
    $filename = $thismoment . "_" . $_GET["t"] . ".gz";
    $mime = "application/x-gzip";

    header( "Content-Type: " . $mime );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"' );

    $cmd = 'D:\Web\XAMPP\mysql\bin\mysqldump --opt -u '.$_user.' -p'.$_pass.' '.$_db.' | gzip --best > backup/' . $filename; 

    passthru( $cmd );

    exit(0);
```

Thanks for the help! You pointed me in the right direction.