# I want to make a php page that recieves post requests and writes the data to a file, the below isn't working

Tags: php

Here is the code, I always have the $data variable set to "" as the requests aren't received properly:

```
<?php
echo"<h1>J_server</h1>";
//receive requests
$data = htmlspecialchars($_POST["incoming_data"] ?? "");
//if not received properly it's defined as ""
if($data != ""){
    if(file_exists("data.log")){
        $file = fopen("data.log","a");
    }else{
        $file = fopen("data.log","w");
    }
    fwrite($file,$data."\n");
    fclose($file);
}else{
    if(file_exists("data.log")){
        $file = fopen("data.log","a");
    }else{
        $file = fopen("data.log","w");
    }
    fwrite($file,"Error in recieving data!!!\n");
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

here is the request code:

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.post("http://localhost/j_server/server.php",data={"incoming_data":"Hello world!"})
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: Add some more information to your answer. What error do you get? Do you get data? If yes? Does your condition run? Try to debug and add information here. Thanks

Comment: I don't get an error it's just not receiving the request so it sets data to "", without the part of code that reassigns the variable i get a undefined index error

Comment: Add the form/ post or submitting code block as the problem might be there. You are not getting $data, maybe you are not posting properly.

Comment: FYI, you can replace all that code with `file_put_contents("data.log", $data, FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` show?'

Comment: it shows: array(0) { }

Comment: @JohnSmith in Python change the `data={"incoming_data":"Hello world!"} ` to `params={"incoming_data":"Hello world!"} ` and then instead of `$_POST` use `$_GET`

Comment: just tried it and still no change

Comment: Try using `$_GET` and putting the variable in the query string `?incoming_data=helloworld`. Does that work?

Comment: no it doesn't...

Comment: Use this to check if there is a post variable set: `if ( isset ( $_POST ["incoming_data"] ) ) {`

Comment: It comes up with undefined index

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```php
<?php

    echo "<h1>Server</h1>";

    if ( isset ( $_POST ["incoming_data"] ) ) {
        $sanitized = htmlspecialchars ( $_POST ["incoming_data"] );
        file_put_contents ( "data.log", $sanitized . "\n", FILE_APPEND );
    }

?>
```

Comment: It's still not working, I think it is something to do with receiving the data rather than processing it but I don't know what it is

Comment: I don't think the code executes because the post request isn't set

Comment: I just tested using python and requests the same way that you do and it worked for me. This could be a permission issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566838/885475