# open file and download does not work in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, php, html, ubuntu, file-upload

i complete my code on windows xampp to download text(or other file) file and its work good
but when i upload the code on ubuntu server its does not work
can you help me plz

```php
$file = "$username.rsc";
$txt = fopen($file, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($txt,
"{
anything
}

");
fclose($txt);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
  ob_clean();
    flush();
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
readfile($file);
```

the response on ubuntu is Unable to open file!

Comment: where is `$file` defined? What's it's value?

Comment: in first its name of file and execution
`$file = "$username.cfg";`
i search and think its about permissions but i did not know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permissions issue. Make sure that your Apache user and group has access to the file and directory that you are trying to modify.

Comment: in:
/var/www/html$ls -la

what should i do ?

Comment: @MohammedAl-Aazawy whats the output of `ls -l` inside your project directory? In Ubuntu I believe the default apache user is `www-data` so as a temp fix you could use `chown www-data:www-data ./* -R` **INSIDE OF YOUR PROJECT DIRECTORY**. Make sure you check to see who the current user and group is that way you can revert it back should something go wrong.

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 5 sinan www-data  4096 Apr 22 12:31 .

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900690/how-do-i-give-php-write-access-to-a-directory